# Using lambda in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to use lambda do to some sorting on a list. What I wanted to do is sort the coordinates based on their manhattan distance from an inital poisition. I know I have most of the syntax down but it seems like I am missing something small, Thanks!

```
while (len(queue) > 0):  
    queue.sort(queue, lambda x: util.manhattanDistance(curr,x))
```

Comment: As a side note, control statements in Python do not need (and should not have) parentheses: `while len(queue) > 0:`. But, since 0 is false and any other integer is not, this is identical to `while len(queue):`. And, since an empty sequence is false and any other sequence is not, this is identical to `while queue:`. And that's how you should write it—it's more idiomatic, easier to read, shorter, and possibly even more efficient.

Comment: One more problem I just noticed: You're passing `queue` as the first argument to `queue.sort`. Whatever type `queue` is, that's not right. (Oh, and don't call a variable `queue`; that's the name of a standard library module.)

Comment: Also: `sort` is not going to change the length of the object, so this is just going to loop forever, re-sorting an already-sorted list over and over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to tell the `sort()` method to use your lambda function as the **key** for sorting. This is done with the **keyword argument** `key`:

`queue.sort(queue, key = [your lambda function])`

The rewritten line is:

`queue.sort(queue, key = lambda x: util.manhattanDistance(curr,x))`

EDIT: misunderstood the purpose of the original lambda function; thought it was intended as a comparison function, which doesn't make sense since distance functions can't be negative

Comment: +1. But it's probably worth explaining that, as orginally written (in 2.x), the OP _is_ using the `lambda` as a `cmp` function, and that's exactly why it's not working. (In Python 3, the code would actually work as written.)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know the order of the keyword arguments and didn't want to look it up. I think the key take-away here is that it is far safer to explicitly specify keyword arguments.

Comment: Definitely agreed. Besides being safer, and making your code work with both 2.x and 3.x (and IIRC, `2to3` won't fix this problem), it's also much easier to read. _Nobody_ remembers what the order is. The only reason to ever use a `cmp` function without a keyword is if you need to be compatible with Python 2.3 or earlier.

Comment: is the x in the lambda function symbolizing each element in the list?

Comment: Yes; the `x` represents each element, and the function itself returns the value associated with that element for the purpose of sorting the list.