# Lambda function Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, lambda

I am having trouble with the lambda function and not really understanding it completely. I am trying to calculate the manhattan distance between two points, 1 point is the current location and the second point is from a list that contains multiple positions. Any help is appreciated, thank you

my function is:

```
toVisit.sort(toVisit,key = lambda x: util.manhattanDistance(curr,x))
```

I am trying to get a value out of the toVisit list but don't know how to exactly. I was thinking of passing in x with the curr location but that does not work.

Comment: Where are you getting curr from?

Comment: Unless `toVisit` is a very unusual type, you should not be passing it as the first argument to `toVisit.sort`. It doesn't need a copy of itself. And I already explained that in a comment to [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636569/using-lambda-in-python).

Comment: curr is given from the parameter, as the current position of pacman, (x,y) and the list contain the 4 corner position in the form (x,y)

Comment: @abarnert , yes I saw it but did not understand what you meant exactly

Comment: We would expect to see code like this: `something.sort()`  We do not expect to see code like you have: `something.sort(something)`  In Python, method functions on an object do not need a reference to the object passed in to the call.  The only place I can think of where I would expect to see something like that is plain C code.

Comment: @steveha: Even in C, you would rarely do `something.sort(something)`. That would imply that you're simulating prototype-style OO instead of the more common class-style OO, and passing them around by value instead of by pointer…

Comment: @abarnert, I agree.  I was trying to think of any example where you would see anything like that.  Probably more confusing than illuminating, now that I think more about it.

Comment: @steveha: I thought of a case. Unless I'm remembering wrong. In Dylan, it's an idiom for avoiding multimethod dispatch. While `obj.meth(arg)` is the same thing as `meth(obj, arg)`, and will pick an implementation based on the types of both `obj` and `arg`, `obj.meth(obj, arg)` picks its implementation based only on the type of `obj`. (This is just a convention—it's actually still picking based on the types of `obj`, `obj`, and `arg`, but you arrange for `arg` to not matter in this case). But somehow, I'm guessing most new Python programmers aren't coming from Dylan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) (or built-in help, or [how-to](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). The signature for `list.sort` is:

```
s.sort([cmp[, key[, reverse]]]) sort the items of s in place    (7)(8)(9)(10)
```

The notes explain, among other things, what each of those parameters mean. In particular, the first parameter, `cmp`:

> specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (list items)

You're passing `toVisit` as the first argument. So, `toVisit` will be used as a comparison function. You can't possibly have thought that was what you wanted. So, I'm guessing you probably don't get the basics of objects and dot notation, and you need to read an appropriate tutorial. (Sorry, I don't have one to recommend. I checked the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html), but it seems to assume that dot notation, and what a method is, and so on are all just obvious and need no explanation…)

Here's the right version:

```
toVisit.sort(key = lambda x: util.manhattanDistance(curr,x))
```

---

Meanwhile, there doesn't seem to be any problem with the `lambda` function itself, but you seem to be convinced, in two questions in a row, that the `lambda` is the part you're having trouble with. If you ever have trouble with a `lambda`, the easiest thing to do is transform it into a normal named function, which is trivial to do.

Where you have this:

```
lambda ARGS: EXPR
```

Do this a line above it:

```
def good_name_for_what_expr_does(ARGS):
    return EXPR
```

Then, replace the `lambda ARGS: EXPR` with `good_name_for_what_expr_does`.

So, this is equivalent to your original code:

```
def manhattanDistanceFromCurr(x):
    return util.manhattanDistance(curr, x)
toVisit.sort(toVisit, key = manhattanDistanceFromCurr)
```

Can you see the problem there any more easily than in the `lambda` version?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do a Google search for "Python introduction to lambda".  Here's the first result, which is a nice explanation:

http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/